# Can't start OpenVPN

Tags: linux, openvpn

When starting `OpenVPN` on Gentoo Linux I get the following error.

```
# openvpn /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf 
Wed Mar  8 00:55:00 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.12 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Mar  7 2017
Wed Mar  8 00:55:00 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.08
Wed Mar  8 00:55:00 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Mar  8 00:55:00 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]172.98.67.7:1198
Wed Mar  8 00:55:01 2017 [28624468b5f74825ffa12e8a33e573f3] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]172.98.67.7:1198
Wed Mar  8 00:55:03 2017 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)
Wed Mar  8 00:55:03 2017 Exiting due to fatal error
```

Some Google results suggested manually creating the `tun` device with `mknod`, this generates a new error

```
# mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
# openvpn /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf 
Wed Mar  8 00:57:25 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.12 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Mar  7 2017
Wed Mar  8 00:57:25 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.08
Wed Mar  8 00:57:25 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Mar  8 00:57:25 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]172.98.67.124:1198
Wed Mar  8 00:57:25 2017 [3ccec8eea78838d4b5676ec98bd25713] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]172.98.67.124:1198
Wed Mar  8 00:57:27 2017 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such device (errno=19)
Wed Mar  8 00:57:27 2017 Exiting due to fatal error
```

I have tun built into my Kernel as shown below. `uname` output also provided

```
$ grep tun /lib/modules/4.10.1/modules.builtin
kernel/drivers/net/tun.ko
...
...

$ uname -a
Linux acer 4.10.1 #5 SMP Sun Mar 5 04:04:19 -00 2017 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Are there any steps I may have forgotten? Other than `tun` are there any more Kernel modules I would need to install?

Comment: See how your errno changed from 2 (no such file) to 19 (no such device)? As you suggest: you need to load the tun module. The `lsmod` or `modprobe` commands are missing from your post, ... Can you confirm it's there?

Comment: If tun is built into the kernel do I need to separately do `modprobe tun`? I ran `modprobe tun` anyway and it completed without any stdout/stderr and returned exit status zero. (which I expect for built in modules)

Comment: this is why `lsmod|grep tun` could have been useful on your post. I can tell I have an openvpn server whose only line in `/etc/modules` is loading `tun`. Now did I add it for safety, troubleshooting something else, ... I couldn't tell for sure. Are you able to start openvpn now? What does your status says?

Comment: Is there a difference between tun being built as a module and being built into the kernel? As I demonstrated with the output from `modules.builtin` tun is available in my kernel . `lsmod | grep tun` would not have yielded any results but this is what we expect since it's a built in.

Comment: Didn't pay attention to the `builtin` suffix, indeed you're right.

Comment: @David, can you check if there is tun support enabled in the kernel? You may try this to check: `test ! -c /dev/net/tun && echo  tun support needed || echo tun ok`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell from `strace` output `modprobe` will blindly trust what `modules.builtin.bin` says is builtin. If that file is out of sync with your actual kernel I expect `modprobe` to return success even if the module isn't there.

Through `/proc` you can find out if the driver is actually loaded. This is a `misc` driver, so you have to look in two locations.

In `/proc/devices` you will find two sections listing character devices and block devices. You should find this character device:

```
 10 misc
```

Next look in `/proc/misc` for the minor number of each driver. You should look for this:

```
200 tun
```

If you find the `misc` driver is present, but `tun` is missing from `/proc/misc` chances are your `modules.builtin.bin` file does not actually correspond to the kernel you are running.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem then I tried it from root and it worked. Might be worth a try

Comment: Since the question shows `#` prompts, the OP is probably already running as root.

Comment: You don't need to be root to open `/dev/net/tun` so surely you must have had a different problem.